# Is there any trick to collecting data from a web page that using JavaScript and setting current time and date automatically?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, wget, javascript, httrack

I work under Ubuntu Linux in the terminal, using shell script `wget`, `httrack` and:

```
google-chrome --headless --dump-dom 'https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/sys/taikikanshi/kanshi/realtime/index.html' > ~/file.html
```

I want to extract these lines hourly from the above site:

```html
< tr class="tr_line_1">
< td class="le" id="station1" headers="stationTop" height="40px" >神奈川県< /td >
< td class="le" id="station1" headers="stationName" height="40px" >鎌倉市役所< /td >
< td class="le" headers="station1 stationDiv" height="40px">一般局 < /td >
…
< td headers="station1 WD WDUnit" height="40px">北東 < /td >
< td headers="station1 WV WVUnit" height="40px">1.2 < /td >
```

(I want to understand the sea breeze conditions near the shores of Sagami Bay. I am a sailing fan and using these data for the private understanding of regattas only.)

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: you can do such things with `python` and `selenium` modul. However, as this is more a programming than an ubuntu question, I guess you should search for an answer / or ask at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: ...  [scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scrapy)